# Error when using GL_RGBA32F for multiple render targets but not with GL_RGBA8

Tags: opengl

When i am using the following code to create multiple render targets and binding with the framebuffer with the texture format `GL_RGBA8`, and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as my data type i am not facing any error.

But when i am doing the same thing with texture format  `GL_RGBA32F`  and `GL_FLOAT` as my data type i am facing the following runtime  error

```
gl error from openglrenderer 0x502 invalid operation framebuffertexture2d
```

The code is as follows:

```
GLuint mFBO = 0;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &mFBO);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFBO);

GLuint mTexColor;
       glGenTextures(1, &mTexColor);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexColor); 
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA32F, 320, 240, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
       glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
       GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexColor, 0);
       GLenum buffers[]   = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0}; glDrawBuffers(1, buffers);
```

Comment: What platform are you developing on?